# Georeferenced images in ArcGIS are projected wrongly in QGIS and other GIS

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, georeferencing

I am working on a big project that includes georeferencing over 850 historical maps in the Netherlands. We're doing this with a small team, with each of us taking certain municipalities.
Since we all prefer the georeferencer in ArcGIS (Pro) we went with this. Eventually these maps are being converted into WMS layers for web publication.

The images are being projected/ referenced in EPSG:28992 (Netherlands, Rd_New). To make sure the maps were being projected correctly, I loaded some of them into QGIS. And all was good.

But now, a couple months later I noticed most of the maps as WMS layers were missing the georeferenced projection. I loaded the maps into QGIS and to my complete surprise, almost all of them are being projected at x:0, y:0, missing any and all projection.

QGIS gives the error (sometimes): N*o transform available between unnamed and EPSG:28992.* The strangest things is that some maps are being projected fine, with no issues.

Things I've tried so far:

1. Trying to warp/reproject the maps in QGIS does nothing, it mostly
   gives errors that the source CRS is unknown. Setting the source to
   EPSG:28992 does nothing as well.
2. I thought that maybe the parameters for the CRS in both ArcGIS and QGIS are different, which causes the error. So I tried making a custom CRS in QGIS with the [ESRI WKT for EPSG:28992](https://epsg.io/28992.esriwkt). But that gives me the error that I cannot create it, because it has the same parameters as QGIS's EPSG:28992.
3. I used FME (I'm very inexperienced) to do some reprojection,  but also no difference whatsoever.

The only things I can think of now is that the additional files that are being saved after georeferencing in ArcGIS are either being read wrongly in QGIS or not at all. Looking at the XML files for some of the maps, it shows some differences. But nothing well enough for me to make out what the problem is and how to fix it.

Is there anything I can do to make the projections correct again?

Edit: Here's an example: https://gofile.io/d/5PAIVw

Comment: What was output format? Did it include world file?

Comment: You still have access to ArcGIS? The georeferenced maps there are in the correct place? Can you provide an example for testing purpose?

Comment: @FelixIP we import them as .tif and export them as (geo) .tif(f). It includes .tfwx files yes. As well as .pgwx, .ovr and .aux.xml files.

Comment: @Babel, Yes I do have an ArcGIS Pro license. Within ArcGIS all the maps are being projected correctly (even the ones we are now georeferencing in QGIS).  I uploaded one of the maps for example here: https://gofile.io/d/pyV5xA.

Comment: The picture you provided seems to be correctly georeferenced (somewhere between Meppel and Dedemsvaart, right?), see: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oKGpe.jpg - just downloaded it, extracted all files to the same folder and used drag-and-drop to get the tif-file in QGIS.

Comment: I have picked a wrong image as an example. This should be a faulty one: https://store9.gofile.io/download/c763c7e3-013b-4072-8e9d-6193a76a3754/Giethoorn%20Sectie%20A%201e%20Blad.zip

Comment: Can't download: `This file is private.`

Comment: It's one of those days I guess. Hope this one works: https://gofile.io/d/5PAIVw

Comment: Yes, but here a `.pgwx`-file (world file) is missing - this might explain the problem.

Comment: But .pgwx if for .png files if i'm not mistaken. .tfwx is the adjacent world file for .tif images. Now I DO think this is causing the issues somehow.

Comment: This gives somewhat of an answer: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/87549/opening-images-georeferenced-aux-xml-in-arcmap-in-qgis

But what does he mean by rectifying? Just georeferencing it again?

Comment: No experience with ArcGIS. But see here, especially under naming convention examples:  "if the transformation cannot be expressed as a world file, the Update Georeferencing command on the Georeferencing toolbar writes the transformation into the .aux.xml file ..." https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/raster-and-images/world-files-for-raster-datasets.htm#GUID-C68E1425-A5E5-4AF3-A0F4-8BAFADF8140C

Comment: Update georeferencing is culprit here. It creates .tfwx file WITH rotation term. Other software will struggle with it. So rectify - yes, Update georeferencing is a NO.

Comment: @FelixIP Thank you! But what is rectifying in ArcGIS Pro? I can't find the Pro equivalent anywhere.

Comment: I have no Pro. Somewhere on georefencing ribbon? Remember warp does the same thing